# What does 'Don't blame it on the pig!' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-play

In the Disney movie 'Moana', Tala who is a grandmother of Moana said **"Whatever just happened... blame it on the pig."**

I've googled and found some headlines like 'Flu? Don't blame the pig', so guessed 'Blame the pig' means blaming someone who is innocent. And the sentence in the movie was a kind of game of words since there is a pig character who is a friend of Moana.

Comment: I have yet to see the movie, but it's probably some kind of joke.  Obviously the pig didn't do it, but you can "blame it on the pig" instead of blaming the actual person who did whatever it was.

Comment: It's not an idiom or stock phrase, so I would guess it refers to an actual pig.  The headlines you found are probably referring to [*swine flu*, a disease that people get from pigs](https://www.google.com/search?q=flu+from+pigs).

Answer (score 2):

Pua, the pig, is one of Moana's side-kicks, with comedic behavior you might find in a puppy-dog.

When Tala sees the damage to the boat, the boat that Moana was not supposed to take beyond the reef, Tala advises Moana to blame the pet pig, so that Moana will not get in trouble for disobeying and for ruining the boat.

She says, "Whatever happened..." (meaning that she doesn't want an explanation) that the best thing for Moana to do would be to, "blame the pig".

http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Pua_(Moana)